# Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none' Violation Error

Tags: javascript, html, apache, mamp, content-security-policy

I have just installed MAMP and created 2 files in the htdocs folder:

- index.html

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
      <body>Test Page</body>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </html>
  ```
- script.js

  ```
  console.log("works");
  ```

MAMP is configured to the following ports:

- Apache Port: 8888
- Nginx port: 7888
- MySQL port: 8889

Opening `localhost:8888` gives the following error in console:

> Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:8888/script.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'".

I have never encountered CSP before, so this has left me bewildered. What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Turns out the cause of this problem was the browser [ScriptSafe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptsafe/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf?hl=en) extension which was turned on. Disabling it solved the issue

Comment: Spent hours trying to solve why I was getting this same problem. Tried all sorts of combinations of CSP headers, but nothing seemed to work. Stumbled on this answer - after all this time it was indeed ScriptSafe that was causing the errors. I disabled it (and also tested with allow/trust/temporary - which worked, too), and managed to get CSP working. Further tested by adding/remove various CSP settings to ensure it definitely worked. I know more and more devs are using script blockers, seeing as we know how easy it is for scripts to pose risks. Thanks @feetnappy!

Comment: Same with NoScript.

Comment: I had Javascript disabled

Comment: So far I have had this problem 4 times. I always end up in this question and this answer

Comment: In my case, it was the "Disable Javascript" extension for Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I turned off javascript earlier in the browser and forgot to turn it back on. Its silly but I m replying here so anyone like me can check it!

Comment: I went crazy bro, I spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong to only find Javascript was disabled